Transition between special Einstein's relativity and relativistic quantum mechanics
In the book "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" by Barrett O'Neill, he defines a material particle as a timelike, future-pointing curve $\alpha: I \rightarrow M$ (worldline) parametrized by arc-length, where $M$ is the spacetime and the parameter $\tau$ represents the proper time.
So, I was thinking that when we quantize, the notion of a trajectory loses its clear meaning. However, we can use Feynman's idea and extend the definition of a quantum material particle to a class of trajectories $[\alpha]$. Perhaps this could be some kind of equivalence class, though I'm not certain. It would be beautiful if this equivalence class or its union formed a Hilbert space, providing a bridge between the realms of relativity and quantum mechanics. But, of course, this entire paragraph is speculative. Maybe, something as:
$$\alpha \sim \beta \iff S[\alpha] - S[\beta] = 2n \pi,$$
for $S$ being the classical action.
I would like to know if there is anything at least similar to this concept. Also, I'm curious whether there is a Feynman path formalism for spacetime trajectories, since string theory essentially uses this formalism for the worldsheet instead of the worldline.
$$Z = \int D[X^\mu(\tau)] e^{iS[X^\mu(\tau)]}.$$
This is similar to Feynman's original idea in quantum mechanics, but here it applies to 4-dimensional curves instead of 3-dimensional ones.
Can anyone help me? Does anyone know if there are similar ideas about these approaches?
My question is: does anyone know of an equivalence relation for possible worldlines that would make the space of equivalence classes a Hilbert space, thereby allowing for a natural quantization in special and general relativity? Is there such an equivalence relation?
Appreciate.

"Can anyone help me?" Help you with what, specifically?

I would like to know if there is any idea in the literature like this of equivalence class and path quantization.

https://www.arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9205205
